# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticateClientAndRetrieveSessionId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, bing-maps, autosuggest

I'm using the Vue.js with Vuetify framework. I need to use a form with a location address field. That field has to suggest the list of location addresses, when the user starts typing in the place name.
[image]
The end goal is to achieve as shown here on Vue js framework: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/autosuggestuiwithoutmap#JS

```html
 <template>
 <v-app>
    <div id="searchBoxContainer">
      <v-text-field
        id="searchBox"
        v-model="startlocation"
        label="Start Location"
        prepend-inner-icon="mdi-map-marker"
        outlined
        rounded
        dense
      ></v-text-field>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=[bing-map apikey]'></script>
```

```js
 metaInfo () {
      return {
        script: [{
          src: `https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=[bing_map apikey]`,
          async: true,
          defer: true,
          callback: () => this.loadMapScenario() // will declare it in methods
        }]
      }
    },
  methods: {
    loadMapScenario() {
       Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.AutoSuggest", {
      callback: () => {
        var options = { maxResults: 5 };
        var manager = new Microsoft.Maps.AutosuggestManager(options);
        manager.attachAutosuggest("#searchBox", "#searchBoxContainer");
      },
    });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this!

I used the snippet that was shared [here](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/autosuggestuiwithoutmap#HTML) and my code now looks like this:

```html
function GetMap() {
                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.AutoSuggest', {
                    callback: onLoad,
                    errorCallback: onError
                });
                function onLoad() {
                    var options = { maxResults: 5 };
                    var manager = new Microsoft.Maps.AutosuggestManager(options);
                    manager.attachAutosuggest('#search_78', '#header-search', selectedSuggestion);
                }
                function onError(message) {
                    document.getElementById('printoutPanel').innerHTML = message;
                }
                function selectedSuggestion(suggestionResult) {
                    document.getElementById('printoutPanel').innerHTML =
                        'Suggestion: ' + suggestionResult.formattedSuggestion +
                            '<br> Lat: ' + suggestionResult.location.latitude +
                            '<br> Lon: ' + suggestionResult.location.longitude;
                }
                
            }
```

After going back to my page, the error changed and it said that my credentials were invalid, and it redirected me to https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Application where I could create a valid key. Using that key fixed the problem and now I can see the suggested addresses form.